# Hold the image on the Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I use this code to pick an image from the device but when the activity is closed the image disappears. How to save it so whenever I open the Activity the image is still there?

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null) {
                Uri imageData = data.getData() ;
                imageView.setImageURI(imageData);



            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you need is save the selected imageUri in local preferences of the activity.

Please check the code below:

```
public class Prefs {
private static Prefs INSTANCE;
private static SharedPreferences prefs;

public static Prefs getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new Prefs();
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}

  public void setImage(String image) {
    prefs.edit().putString("image", image).apply();
}

public String getImage() {
    return prefs.getString("image", "");
}
```

Then in your activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);


if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Prefs.getInstance(applicationContext).getImage()){

val imgFile = File(Prefs.getInstance(getApl).getImage())

            if (imgFile.exists()) {
                val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath())
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
            }
}
```

In your onActivityResult:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null) {
            Uri imageData = data.getData() ;
            imageView.setImageURI(imageData);
Prefs.getInstance(applicationContext).setImage(PathUtils.getPath(applicationContext,imageData));


        }

}
}


public class PathUtils {

public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // DocumentProvider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {// ExternalStorageProvider
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            String storageDefinition;


            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {

                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];

            } else {

                if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
                    storageDefinition = "EXTERNAL_STORAGE";

                } else {
                    storageDefinition = "SECONDARY_STORAGE";
                }

                return System.getenv(storageDefinition) + "/" + split[1];
            }

        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {// DownloadsProvider

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);

        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {// MediaProvider
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }

    } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {// MediaStore (and general)

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);

    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {// File
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}


public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

}

Comment: In principle all ok. But you forgot to tell that this does not work for ACTION_GET_CONTENT. And there are other flaws.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Simply the user wants to imageUrl saved even if the application was closed and opened. So, this is the best outcome

Comment: But it will not work. Did you restart the app and checked if the image is reloaded from the uri? You will get back the uri. That is true. But it is useless as the read permission is no longer valid. But... You can solve that problem.

Comment: You only need the read permission once per session. No one gets the read permission every time. Anyway if you have a better solution please do answer the question. This is what I think would work.

Comment: You did not answer my question: `Did you restart the app and checked if the image is reloaded from the uri?`. Please do.

Comment: @blackapps I tried it just now and I did a minor change of saving the full path instead of the uri

Answer (score 0):

first, you must use cursor for catch media path, then you can store on the hawk or shared preferences with a special key. then open the image with data stored in Hawk or shared preferences.
eg :

```
               Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, 
             filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Hawk.put("image",mediaPath);

            //after_reset =>
            String mediaPath1 = Hawk.get("image").toString();
            channelImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath1));
```